# Convert [Observable<T>] to Observable<[T]> in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Here's my implementation.

I have `favCitiesID = Observable<[Int]>` that will be flatMap and map. Each city id will be used in API call that will return `Observable<CityMappable>`. I have reached to the point where I can get `[Observable<CityMappable>]` but I want to transform it into `Observable<[CityMappable]>` so I can bind it to tableview datasource.

```
let favCitiesID: Observable<[Int]> = Observable.of([0,1,2])

let observableCities = favCitiesID.flatMap { cityIds -> Observable<[CityMappable]> in
        return cityIds.map{ return self.apiManager.getCurrentWeatherData(for: $0)}
}
```

This is APIManager function definition

```
func getCurrentWeatherData(for cityID: Int)->Observable<CityMappable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combine to convert from `[Observable<CityMappable>]` to `Observable<[CityMappable]>`.

Try this code

```
let observableCities = favCitiesID.flatMap { cityIds -> Observable<[CityMappable]> in
    let obs = cityIds.map{ return self.apiManager.getCurrentWeatherData(for: $0)}
    return Observable.combineLatest(obs)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works. Now I'm gonna go and learn how combineLatest work.

Comment: Here's an article about different ways to combine two or more Observables. https://medium.com/@danielt1263/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f